# Use remote laptop screen as extra monitor while connected with Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I have two laptops on my table, which are my private and work laptops, both running Windows 10.

I am using Remote Desktop to connect from my private laptop to my work laptop which are both connected via wi-fi to my home router, so that I can switch between work and home contexts as and when I need to.

My private laptop also is plugged into a monitor via HDMI which I am using as my main display and then my private laptop screen as my secondary display.

The work laptop's screen is therefore now idle.

Would be possible to use my work laptop's screen as a third display somehow (considering that I am already connected to that laptop with Remote Desktop)?

**UPDATE**

So my experience is that, even when first extending across to the work laptop's display, the moment I connect with remote desktop, the screen sharing stops.

So I'm guessing what I am asking is not possible.

Comment: You can try with Synergy at symless.com/synergy, I find it useful when i dont want to waste resource on RDP.

Answer (score 0):

In general, such a problem can be solved with [Spacedesk App](https://www.spacedesk.net/).
The product is quite flexible, you can work out different use scenarios.